# Sort multidimensional array by value unique array keys

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I want to sort Multi dimensional array based up on the value, please check  following array,

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [70000] => Aceh
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [70024] => Sumatera Utara
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [70058] => Barat
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [70078] => Riau
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [70091] => Jambi
        )
)
```

I want it to be like this after sort, please check below array.

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [70000] => Aceh
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [70024] => Barat 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [70058] => Jambi
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [70078] => Riau
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [70091] => Sumatera Utara
        )
)
```

Can any one help me with the good solution please. Thank you!.

Comment: I tried `usort` method but it's working if I have unique array keys.

Comment: Then post your attempts too

Comment: Are you sure you want to swap the values (`Aceh`, etc.) while NOT swapping their keys (`70000`, etc.)?

Comment: yes I want to swap values not keys

Comment: Then Fuser97381's answer will do. But... what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know this way is good or bad but I got wanted output by `usort`

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
      if ($a[key($a)] == $b[key($b)]) return 0;
      return ($a[key($a)] > $b[key($b)]) ? 1 : -1;
   }
usort( $levelOneArray, 'cmp' );
print_r($levelOneArray);
```

Comment: This will not keep the keys (`70000`, etc.) but will re-assign them (`0, 1, 2` etc.). See also [this comparison of sorting functions](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php)

Answer (score 0):

Very strange output that you're after. Use something like this:

```
function weirdSort($array) {
  $out = [];
  $keys = [];
  $values = [];
  foreach($array as $k => $v) {
    $values[] = $v;
    $keys[] = $k;
  }
  usort($values);
  foreach($keys as $i => $key) {
    $out[] = [$key => $values[$i];
  }
  return $out;
}
```